# Colouring spintax code in richtextbox

Tags: c#

I am sending an article to be spun on my server

{*Just to give some background on what is Article spinning: As explained @ http://umstrategies.com/what-is-spintax/:* *Article spinning is a method of creating one or more unique copies of an original article.  The level of uniqueness depends on the type and amount of spinning you do.Typical uses for spun articles are:
a) Submitting to various article directories, b) Submitting to blog networks, c) Creating unique content for a website/blog. In general, the main purpose of spinning articles is to gain backlinks.*
}

, and then my code returns the article to the UI in spintax format i.e. **"{Hello|Hi} are you {today|tonight}?"** and shows it in a RichTextBox.
I need to colour the spintax fields: **{Hello|Hi}** as green in the richTextBox. 
However with my code below, all I see is the html code in the richTextBox.
I'm not exactly sure what is the best way to do this. any tips / help would be appreciated.
Code:

```
string action = e.Argument as string;

if (action == "wraith_spinner_start")
{
    var theThesaurusLanguage = "";

    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        theThesaurusLanguage = ComboBoxThesaurus.Text;
    }));

    try
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            RichTextBoxArticleBody.Text = Helpers.InternalSpinner(
                RichTextBoxArticleBody.Text.ToLower(), theThesaurusLanguage);
            // COLOUR SPINTAX //
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helpers.ReturnMessage(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: So is your question, "how do I detect words separated by pipes inside curly brackets"? I don't see where you are trying to color anything in the code above